# How to pass a type of exception as a parameter?

Tags: c#

I would like to have a method that receives a type of exception (i.e., the parameter passed must be a class that implements System.Exception).

What is the right way to do this?

The following is NOT what I want:

```
public void SetException(Exception e)
```

... that requires an instance of an exception.  I want to pass a type of exception like `InvalidProgramException`

---

**Edit:** To further explain what I want to do, I want to be able to track how many times I have seen an exception of each type before.  So I want to be able to do something like:

```
Dictionary<ExceptionTypeThing, int> ExceptionCounts;

public void ExceptionSeen(ExceptionTypeThing e)
{
    // Assume initialization
    ExceptionCounts[e]++;
}

ExceptionSeen(InvalidProgramException);
```

I don't want to pass an instance of the exception, but rather track it by type of exception.

Comment: what do you want to do? are you sure you need this?

Comment: Please explain what you are actually trying to do.  Passing the type of an exception is trivial (e.g. just make the argument of type `Type` instead of type `Exception`), but whether that addresses your actual need is not clear. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but the "best" way depends on how you're planning on using the exception type inside the method.  Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: Added a comment to explain in more detail

Comment: Your edit begs a question why do you count it? What you're going to do with that?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - that's hardly relevant.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is. I believe this is the XYProblem, so I can help him with the original problem if it happens to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a generic method

```
public void SetException<TException>() where TException : Exception
{
    ExceptionCounts[typeof(TException)]++;
}
```

You can call it as

```
SetException<InvalidProgramException>();
```

Edit:

```
Dictionary<Type, int> ExceptionCounts;
public void ExceptionSeen(Type type)
{
    ExceptionCounts[type]++;
}
```

Call it as

```
ExceptionSeen(typeof(MyException));
```

Or if you have the exception instance already

```
ExceptionSeen(ex.GetType());
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm confused as OP said *The following is NOT what I want:* I assume he just needs the type of exception not instance.

Comment: But ExceptionSeen doesn't enforce that it is an Exception passed, right?  Whereas normal parameters specify a type to ensure that type is passed.

Comment: @gnychis It doesn't. If you want to enforce it at compile time, you need to use generics as explained in my first part of my answer. If it can be runtime, you can just check whether `type` is subclass of Exception and throw exception if not.

Comment: In the first part of your error, can you help me figure out how to use TException?  How can I now do ExceptionCounts[TException] ....

Comment: Got it.  And about this: `Dictionary<ExceptionTypeThing, int> ExceptionCounts;`  I'm assuming `s/ExceptionTypeThing/Type` ... but is there any compile time enforcement there also?

Comment: No, that could just be `Dictionary<Type, int>` if you modify it only inside this method. It will be safe. If you need it to be compile time safe, you need to create a generic class for this purpose. I guess that's a overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Define a generic method that does *not* take an instance, then use the generic type constraint to force it to inherit from `Exception`:

```
public void SetException<T>() where T : Exception
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pass a type, specify 'Type' as the paramteer type, then if you want to make sure that is is of exception type you need to check the type at runtime:

```
public void SetException(Type t) {
    if (!typeof(Exception).IsAssignableFrom(t)) {
       throw new ArgumentException("t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
public void SetException(Type type)

SetException(typeof(InvalidProgramException))
// or
SetException(e.GetType)
```

Another options is to use generics to help

```
public void SetException<T>()    
SetException<InvalidProgramException>()
```

or

```
public void SetException<T>(T exception)    
SetException(e);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can create your custom class that inherit base exception i.e. exception class and then you can  pass any type of exception in your method by parameter type of your custom class that you already created.

Comment: That doesn't really address the question.